# Which multi-vendor WordPress plugin can I use that has the feature of setting a fixed fee for a subscription for vendors?

Tags: e-commerce, dokan

I am attempting to build a multi-vendor WordPress e-commerce site. I downloaded "Dokan" plugin, but when configuring the settings, there was no option that can control the vendors subscription with a fixed fee. The option I saw was a fixed fee on every item. However, I want it to be a fixed fee on Monthly basis. Please I need help on this. [An image of dokan setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJkcw.png)

Answer (score 0):

subscription is a part of their pro version, not the free version if you are using pro check this document: https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/modules/how-to-install-use-dokan-subscription/